# Почему читает не с конца таблицы, а сначала?

Tags: c#, mysql

```
        int id_logs = 0;
        int id = 0;
        int id_events = 0;
        string MyCommand = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " ORDER BY '" + id_log + "' DESC";
        OdbcCom = new OdbcCommand(MyCommand, OdbcCon);
        OdbcDR = OdbcCom.ExecuteReader();
        while (OdbcDR.Read())
        {
            id_logs = OdbcDR.GetInt32(0);
            id = OdbcDR.GetInt32(1);
            id_events = OdbcDR.GetInt32(2);

            Console.Write("ID:" + OdbcDR.GetInt32(0).ToString());
            Console.Write("ID:" + OdbcDR.GetInt32(1).ToString());
            Console.Write("ID:" + OdbcDR.GetInt32(2).ToString());
           // if (id == id_tribune)
              //  break;
        }
        OdbcDR.Dispose();
        OdbcCom.Dispose();
```

Comment: Ну для начала было бы неплохо сделать Console.Write(MyCommand) и показать, что оно выведет.

Comment: Ну вообще то я сделал))))
Console.Write("ID:" + OdbcDR.GetInt32(0).ToString());
выдает все правильно, за исключением того, что данные берутся с первой строки, а не с последней

Comment: Извиняюсь...сейчас напишу, что выдает.. там тоже все правильно

Comment: вот, что выдает:
SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY 'id_log' DESC

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, проблема в том, что `id_log` у Вас в кавычках, и СУБД считает выражением не колонку, по которой Вы сортируете, а константную строку. Понятное дело, после этого выводится то, в каком порядке данные получены непосредственно из таблицы, т.к. константное выражение для сортировки на эту сортировку не влияет.

Comment: Если не ставить кавычки выводится ошибка синтаксиса.

Comment: Хорошее замечание, уберите кавычки!

Comment: Попробуйте заменить кавычки апострофами. `

Comment: дык и стоят апострофы. на кавычки тоже ругается.

Answer (score 1):

Ура! Получилось.

```
SELECT * FROM " + table + " ORDER BY '' + id_log + '' DESC;
```

Точно апострофы нужно. Спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Дело в том, что читать оно будет **ВСЕГДА СНАЧАЛА**, оператор DESC выводит результатирующие таблицы в обратном порядке на выходе! То есть, сначала запрос считывает от первой до последней записи(**ЧИТАЯ СНАЧАЛА, ВСЕГДА СНАЧАЛА ИДЁТ ЧТЕНИЕ**), а уже после включает оператор DESC который выводит в обратном порядке результат запроса!

Comment: Ну а как мне на выходе то получить данные? в переменную из засунуть и возвратить? этот язык я начал 2 дня назад изучать))

Comment: Я сам в C# не работал с БД, но по логике, результат можно поместить в коллекцию / массив и там уже с ним проводить манипуляции. Смотрите в Visual Studio что возращает OdbcDR.Read() и на основе этого работайте с информацией. Когда пишите VS Вам покажет какой тип даннх возвращает OdbcDR.Read()

Comment: Не понять за что -1, если кто то не согласен обоснуйте.

Comment: Можно и так, но в базу постоянно будут добавляться новые данные, 57 источников данных, и 22 события. времени много уходить будет, не говоря уж о размере буфера...

Comment: если точнее, меня интересует последнее событие с определенного источника данных.

Comment: Вот код для выборки последнего события: SELECT * FROM logs ORDER BY id_log DESC LIMIT 1; А вообще не используйте звёздочку, лучше явно указать поля для выборки.

Comment: За то, что `OdbcDataReader` обходит результат выполнения запроса, а не записи, полученные из таблицы, перед сортировкой, и Ваше предположение о том, что дело в этом, заведомо неверно, Вы пытаетесь отвечать, недостаточно уяснив вопрос.

Comment: Вы сами поняли что написали? 
Цитирую: "За то, что OdbcDataReader обходит результат выполнения запроса, а не записи, полученные из таблицы", а результат выполнения запроса, это не те данные, которые мы запрашивали? Здесь не предположение, а неверный SQL запрос во всех смыслах. Если нужно выбрать последнее событие из таблицы, то нужно было модифицировать запрос, и исправить ошибки.

Comment: Результат выполнения запроса - это те данные, которые мы запрашивали. Но вовсе не обязательно это будут записи, полученные из таблицы. В данном случае они подвергаются ещё и сортировке. А также может быть агрегация, объединение и прочее. Так что это Вы сами себе противоречите, а не я.